# Filling ListView with AsyncTask (doInBackground() returning cursor)

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-cursor

I'm trying to fill my ListView using AsyncTask. Included problem in the comment

```
private class DownloadDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Cursor> {
    private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(ctx);


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog.setMessage(ctx.getString(R.string.AcquiringData));
        this.dialog.show();
    }


    @Override
    protected Cursor doInBackground(final String... args) {         

        DbAdapter dbAdapter = new DbAdapter(ctx);
        dbAdapter.open();
        // normally when I call this method from main class it reurns cursor full of values
        Cursor cursor = dbAdapter.fetchAllItemsInExpenses();

        return cursor;
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(final Cursor cursor) {
        if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
            this.dialog.dismiss();
           //cursor is empty

    }
```

`ctx` is Context that is set on the main class OnCreate()

Following requests pasting the fetchAllItemsInExpenses() method:

```
public Cursor fetchAllItemsInExpenses() {
    String query = "SELECT ... " //(some terribly boring and long query string, but trust me, it works perfectly fine)
    return SQLDb.rawQuery(query, null);
}
```

Comment: check using `if(null!=cursor){cursor.getCount()}` and also check your method `fetchAllItemsInExpenses` is proper or not

Comment: Can you show `fetAllItemsInExpenses()` source? Also, have you looked into using a [`CursorLoader`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) before?

Comment: fetchAllItemsInExpenses() worked fine  when I was calling it from Activity class. Takes some time however so I decided to move list filling to AsyncTask. Provided the code however. @JasonRobinson correct me If I'm wrong the Cursor loader is kind of a task designed for loading cursors?

Comment: @JacekKwiecień hence the name :)

Comment: @JasonRobinson could you provide me with some example of using it? I just read that for andoid < 3.0 I have to use some compatibiliti libraries... EDIT: yeah... it is from API 11 :/

Comment: @JacekKwiecień http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_loading-data_cursorloader/

Comment: Like you said, it's available in the support package all the way back to API 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in the `AsyncTask`...

```
private class DownloadDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Cursor> {
    private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(ctx);
    Context ctx = null; //Add this and the constructor below

    public DownloadDataTask(Context context) {
        ctx = context;
    }

    ...

}
```

Then in your `Activity` create and execute the `AsyncTask` as follows...

```
DownloadDataTask ddt = new DownloadDataTask(this);
ddt.execute(theArgs);
```

Comment: how does that change anything? my ctx variable initialized on OnCreate of activity holds the same thing

Comment: You said your `ctx` is part of the `Activity` - you shouldn't be trying to access anything in the `Activity` (UI thread) from the `doInBackground` thread. Passing it in to a constructor allows `doInBackground` to access the `AsyncTask` `ctx`.

Comment: makes sense... I'' try it as soon the bloody x10 boots again